# Does a dictionary exist that goes from full word -> abbreviation? Many only offer abbreviation -> full word

Tags: resources, dictionary

My question is about 简称 ("abbreviations"). The question is simple: where can I find a dictionary that includes abbreviations in its definitions?

For example, the NDRC here in Beijing is technically 国家发展和改革委员会, but everyone here calls it 发改委. A CC-DICT or nciku search may direct me from the abbreviation to the full word (i.e., if I search for 发改委, it will tell me it is an abbreviation for 国家发展和改革委员会). But I want something that includes the abbreviation for a given entry (i.e., if I search for 国家发展和改革委员会, it will say 'hey by the way, you should know that it is commonly abbreviated as 发改委').

Consider, for example, looking up 家用电器 ('household appliances'). It would be helpful if the dictionary entry included the more common abbreviation 家电.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The English Wiktionary has Chinese entries and lists synonyms, including ones which are abbreviations. But of course it's very far from complete since it's just built by volunteers in their spare time.

Answer (score 3):

The baidu baike (http://baike.baidu.com/) often has the abbreviation listed under the main entry. 中华人民共和国国家发展和改革委员会, for example, has 国家发改委.  中华人民共和国国务院办公厅 lists both 国务院办公厅 and 国办.  And yes, 家用电器 points to 家电 as the simpler form, although it is somewhat hidden in the entry.

Answer (score 1):

Look for news articles, especially those from Xinhua, which are considered "official". Typically if an article contains a long-winding name like "人力资源和社会保障部", it is bound to introduce an abbreviation to reduce the verbosity. If you cannot find such articles, which should be unlikely for well-known entities, I suggest that you not abbreviate, especially not invent an abbreviation, as not even native Chinese can always be sure what an abbreviation is when expanded in full.